# SQL server, data integrity - table referenced by many tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, data-integrity

I have a table which has some generic data, that must be referenced by a multiple number of other tables. The referenced table can't be simplified to fit columns of the referencing tables. How do I enforce data integrity and relationships in such a scenario?

**Edit**

By saying that the table can't be simplified, I meant that it is not possible to store the needed data in the tables that need that data and get rid of the referenced table.

Comment: Why would you need to add columns to your referenced table to store data about tables referencing it?  That makes zero sense.

Comment: I meant adding data to the referencing tables themselves, instead of created a foreign table, not to the referenced table.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data.  This will help clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two very flexible ways to enforce RI are with:

1. Check Constraints - you can write UDFs that encapsulate the logic you want to enforce, and the constraint just checks the UDF for a true or false.
2. Triggers - The RI logic is written into the trigger code.

Comment: Are there any pros and cons to each of the ways?

Comment: Not generally, no.   Your question is very general so it will be up to you to look at each specific RI need that you want to enforce and decide which one is best in each case.

Comment: Why start with complex and potentially VERY expensive approaches? One of the specific problems RDBMS like SQL Server are designed to solve is RI by the use of PK/FK. It's very lightweight and has little chance of a meltdown unlike custom coded constraints. If the referenced table gets really busy, you'll likely run into performance issues that can be very hard to tune. Additionally triggers, can increase transaction log growth rates so you have to tune that too. Don't see why that's a good starting point compared to defining native PK/FK constraints between the tables. What am I missing?

Comment: I **am** using FKs for relationships, but in this particular case I need some more complex logic, so I would not loose track of objects, which are meaningless without their children.

Answer (score 0):

-> must be referenced by a multiple number of other tables.

Okay, so there must be common column(s) between 'a table' and 'other tables' so you can create a foreign key relationship.

-> The referenced table can't be simplified to fit columns of the referencing tables.

Really not sure what you mean here, so please spell this out.   If you can't have common column(s), then you'll need to make a design change based on your requirements.